# trigger a zsh function based on string match of any command's stdout/stderr?

Tags: zsh

This is surprisingly hard to search for.
The only thing I can find, are TRAP* functions, which can be triggered via various signals.

But I really want to watch all stdout/stderr, and have a function trigger if a certain string is matched.

(example: refreshing kerberos credentials. A command fails and emits a standard error message indicating I need to authenticate. I want to automatically run the command to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

The shell doesn't see a command's stdout/stderr if not piped to the shell. So, you need to redirect stdout/stderr to your zsh function. But you can also send them to both your zsh function and somewhere else. For instance:

```
your_command 2>&1 | tee >(your_zsh_function)
```

or

```
your_command |& tee >(your_zsh_function)
```

or

```
your_command >>(your_zsh_function) >>/dev/tty 2>&1
```

`your_zsh_function` will grep its input for a string match. A drawback is that you may have buffering problems.

But concerning your example, if I understand correctly, you may want to use the `expect` utility: "programmed dialogue with interactive programs".